# Windows 7 file permission

Tags: windows, filesystems

I am Suffering a problem after installing Windows 7 on my PC.  In my "E" Drive I am not able to execute any file (*.*).  When I double click on any file it gives me the error:

```
Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  
You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item.
```

- I changes the permition and assign full control but its useless
- reindexd the file system
- Used the Diskcheck

And the amaging thing is when i copy any file from "E:" to another drive it works fine

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur if any of the following scenarios exist on your PC.

- You do not have permissions to the file or the file location.
- The file is on a location that is not currently accessible like a network location or an external drive that is not currently connected to the PC.
- The file has been moved or deleted.
- The file or shortcut is corrupt.
- The file may be blocked by Windows.
- Your antivirus software may be blocking the file.

The solution is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669244).

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply but i allready tryed all those solution and "if the file will be currupeted then how it run after copy in another drive" "if the antivirus blocks the file then it should not run again in another location"

Comment: 1.corrupted file move to another drive 2.blocked the file not run any location. this is your requirement?

Comment: thans again for your attention but my problem is when i copy my file from e drive to any other drive (eg. f:\,g:\,h:\) then it works fine but in e drive not a single application can run any file (notpad not opens any document file,media files are not being open by mediaplayer or any othr player) including EXE files also

Comment: Are you able to open e drive ? atleast you can view the file inside the e drive?

Comment: yes i am able to open e drive and seems all well till i dont try to open any file

Comment: Have you tried recursively [taking ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) of all the files on the drive?

Comment: Hi friends thanks for all of your attention

My problem is now solved
I copyed my whole drive in another drive then format it and again copy back all files and folders.
and now it functioning normally

i think the problem was with my file system